# My session is closed before the set time is reached...?

Tags: javascript, php, session

i've a function here idleTimer. I want to destroy the function when 5000ms are gone and redirect to login page. Before the five seconds are gone and I redirect to another page, the session is already destroyed. I want that the session_destroy only takes place after the five seconds... With this code, the redirecting works but like i said before, the session is destroyed before 5 sec.

Could someone help me?

```
function idleTimer() 
        {
            var t;
            window.onload = resetTimer;
            window.onmousemove = resetTimer; // catches mouse movements
            window.onmousedown = resetTimer; // catches mouse movements
            window.onclick = resetTimer;     // catches mouse clicks
            window.onscroll = resetTimer;    // catches scrolling
            window.onkeypress = resetTimer;  //catches keyboard actions


            function logout() 
            {
                <?php
                    session_destroy(); // the problem is here!
                ?>

                window.location.href = './Login.html';
            }
           function resetTimer() 
            {
                clearTimeout(t);
                t = setTimeout(logout, 5000);
            }

        }
```

Comment: You cannot mix javascript and PHP like this. They have completely discontinuous life spans - PHP finishes and sends to the client first

Comment: Do you know how to end the session and redirect after it in Javascript or do you have other method?

Comment: use the `logout` function to redirect to a php script that terminates the session and redirect from that script to final `login.html`

Comment: `session_destroy(); // the problem is here!` - In either case, you still have to start  the session.

Comment: Thanks I made a logout script, session start, session destroy and changed the href to that logout script instead of the login, like you said and it works now!

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.href = './Login.php?sessionDestroy=true';
```

file login.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['sessionDestroy')){
  session_destroy();
}
```

don't forget to change the login file extension to php